# SSO Ticket expired

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I am new to SAP and receiving SSO ticket expired issue while running reports in Analysis for office.

Below is the error that I am receiving, does someone know about how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you read [this](https://scn.sap.com/thread/790908)?

Comment: What is *Analysis for office*?